# Problem with serializing object field Django

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am not a newbie in Django REST Framework, but still not understand something in serialization.
For example, I need to serialize a object field that is an object too. From this object field I need only one field (e.g "title"). I know, that is possibly to create the following to solve my project:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'title')


class GarageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        depth = 1
        model = Garage
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'address', 'car_set')

    car_set = CarSerializer(many=True)
```

This serializer will return

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "MyGarage",
    "address": "Paris",
    "car_set": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Lamborghini"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to find way how to point on fields of child field like this:

```
Car.objects.filter(garage__title='MyGarage')
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you could just do it as it is in the views with get_queryset fumction, according to documentation:

```
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/
```

exemple:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username')
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks @taha but it won't work. Because with this function we are able to sort or filter the queryset, but not change fields. I think the problem in serializers.